# Editable Text() [ Text() that can be TextField() on double tap]

Tags: swiftui

Some time ago I had a problem with making UI logic of view that can be Label and EditBox both:

I mean `Text()` -> doubleClick action -> display `TextEdit()` -> fill it with new text -> Enter key press -> text changes saved and displayed in `Text()`

solution is in answer below

Comment: Self-answered questions must meet the same quality guidelines as any other question here. This one does not, as it does not clearly explain a problem and ask a specific question. You should edit it to improve it. The same applies to your answer - it does nothing to explain how it solves the problem or why the code you posted does so.

Comment: @KenWhite So do you mean that I must to edit question and add "minimal reproducible example" or any another non-working code to post working code as an answer?

Comment: No, it just needs to be a clearly explained problem and there should be an actual question asked. The answer needs an explanation describing how it answers that qusetion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public struct EditableLabel: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @State private var newValue: String = ""
    
    @State var editProcessGoing = false { didSet{ newValue = text } }
    
    let onEditEnd: () -> Void
    
    public init(_ txt: Binding<String>, onEditEnd: @escaping () -> Void) {
        _text = txt
        self.onEditEnd = onEditEnd
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Text variation of View
            Text(text)
                .opacity(editProcessGoing ? 0 : 1)
            
            // TextField for edit mode of View
            TextField("", text: $newValue, 
                          onEditingChanged: { _ in }, 
                          onCommit: { text = newValue; editProcessGoing = false; onEditEnd() } )
                .opacity(editProcessGoing ? 1 : 0)
        }
        // Enable EditMode on double tap
        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: { editProcessGoing = true } )
        // Exit from EditMode on Esc key press
        .onExitCommand(perform: { editProcessGoing = false; newValue = text })
    }
}
```

sample of usage:

```
EditableLabel($name, onEditEnd: { print("New name is *\(name)* ") } )
```

Comment: Why not just use an if-else statement instead of opacity? Now both views are part of the hierarchy while only one is needed at a time. Then the `ZStack` is no longer necessary either.

Comment: Because of "if else" statement will be the reason of unexpected change of size of element. Text is absent - view have one size. Text is exist - view have another size. This looks really bad.

Comment: When hovering the cursor is an I-bar instead of a pointer. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Amzd/cb8ba40625aeb6a015101d357acaad88