# value of @FocusState cannot be changed in the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a View with a text and a textfield.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool
    var body: some View {
        @State var text: String = "test"
        
        if focused {
            TextField("name", text: $text)
        } else {
            Text(text)
                .onTapGesture {
                    $focused.wrappedValue = true
                    print(focused)
                }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
        .padding(100)
}
```

output:

```
false
false
false
false
false
```

I want to display the text according to the fact that if user is editing or not. But the @FocusState just cannot be modified in the onTapGesture. I checked the detail. Is it because @FocusState's wrappedValue is a read-only property? Then how should I implement this feature?

Comment: I am very confused by your code. Instead of just having an unfocused `TextField`, you want to display a `Text` instead? Why? I'd imagine this design will confuse a lot of users.

Comment: Are you trying to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67864506/5133585)?

Comment: @sweeper sorry about the confusing code, I am still a beginner.  What you said is really inspiring.  Maybe I should just consider using TextField in an editable context.

Answer (score 1):

The second `Text` is showing the value of the state variable that is editable in the `TextField`. So would I be right in thinking that you want to use a different appearance when the text is not being edited?

- I think you need to associate the `FocusState` variable with a field that can actually accept focus, and the field needs to exist in the layout.
- To set the variable to true, just use `focused = true`
- Also, the state variable `text` should be declared as a `View` property, not as a variable inside the scope of `body`.

It works if you show the `TextField` as an overlay over the `Text`, with opacity conditional on the `focused` variable.

Like this:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool
    @State private var text: String = "test"

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Text(text)
                .frame(maxWidth: 100, minHeight: 30)
                .onTapGesture {
                    focused = true
                    print(focused)
                }
                .overlay {
                    TextField("name", text: $text)
                        .focused($focused)
                        .padding(4)
                        .border(.primary)
                        .background(.background)
                        .opacity(focused ? 1 : 0)
                }
            if focused {
                Button("Done") {
                    focused = false
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 100, alignment: .top)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 0):

Note, you should not declare `@State var text: String = "test"` inside
the `body` of the view.

`...to display the text according to the fact that if user is editing or not`, try this approach as shown in the example code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool
    @State var text: String = "test"
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $text).border(.red)
            .focused($focused)
        
        if focused {
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the differences and where my problem is.